# How to move a nodejs server from a pc to a beaglebone Black?

Tags: node.js, beagleboneblack

I have created an app which allows a user to control LED's using a mobile or a web browser.

Firstly,to check my work I created a **nodejs** server on my PC,then I configured the **buildroot** of a beaglebone Black.

Now I want to put the server on the beaglebone which will communicate with the web interface.

How can I put the folder containing the application from the pc to beaglebone?

Should I create a package and put the application inside it?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way of doing this is using a tool like [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) to transfer the files to the BeagleBone. Or you may consider a git repo, from which you can pull the necessary files. Of course, these methods deal with just bringing the necessary node server source to your BeagleBone - managing your node.js install, if it isn't on your BeagleBone already, is another separate issue.